# Excel VBA protect sheet, but allow paste values

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I can protect my sheet, but I want to allow users paste values from another excel manually in **editinRange**, but I don't want that user takes formatting also with the paste.

Here is my current code.

```
Private ws As Worksheet 


Sub protectSheet()

Dim editingRange As Range
Set editingRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(4, 2), ws.Cells(22, 10))

    ws.Protect

    With editingRange
        .EnableOutlining = True
        .Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
        .Protect Password:="", _
        DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True
    End With

End Sub
```

My coding challenge illustrated.

[image]

---

I went to see proposed link below and copied from there code which works partially. Now the code generates an error announcement, when I try to copy some of excel files data. I want that that the code doesn't care anything about the formatting etc. It just copies values and pastes that into my tool.

> PasteSpecial method of Range class failed

[image]

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim UndoString As String
    Dim srce As Range
    Dim trgt As Range

    UndoString = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)
    If left(UndoString, 5) = "Paste" Then 'Only allow Paste Special|Values

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.EnableEvents = False

            Application.Undo
            Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Application.EnableEvents = True

    ElseIf UndoString = "Auto Fill" Then

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        Set trgt = Selection

        Application.Undo

        Set srce = Selection

        srce.Copy

        trgt.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                    :=False, Transpose:=False

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If


Application.CutCopyMode = True
  Exit Sub

err_handler:
    MsgBox "Something went wrong when pasting the values."
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Check out this: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/230718-force-paste-special-values.html

Comment: Thanks. I got started, but now I am facing other challenges.

Comment: You better make a new question.